# How to parse local scope variable in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am trying to parse string to object array in my React application.

```
const {newsEntity} = props;
const contentInString = {newsEntity.content}; <== not working
// const contents = JSON.parse(contentInString); <== hoping to use this someday
```

I got the following error `ESLint: Parsing error: ',' expected.`

I tried to removed the curly braces but it gives `undefined`

Content :

```
[{"content":"Umi Kalsum berharap kondisinya tetap baik","type":"text"},{"content":"Dream - Setelah menempuh perjalanan darat cukup panjang untuk menemui wanita diduga telah menghina keluarganya, Umi Kalsum dan Ayah Rozak akhirnya kembali rumahnya di Depok, Jawa Barat. Perjalanan panjang itu ternyata menguras tenaga orang tua Ayu Ting Ting tersebut.","type":"text"}
```

The content of `{newsEntity}` I notice only visible during the rendering

```
return (<div> {newsEntity.content}</div>  );
```

Comment: Can you show example data of `newsEntity.content`?

Comment: do you have value in `newsEntity` ?

Comment: `{newsEntity.content}` is a syntax error. Perhaps you meant `newsEntity.content`?

Comment: looks like you have to use map since format is array, so that you can render

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: In a way that is similar to my question, but for context this issue appeared during rendering when the value initially is not defined therefore `?` needed to safeguard it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const contentInString = {newsEntity.content};` this leads to syntax error.

you should extract this way `const contentInString = newsEntity?.content`

Comment: your is working too. Apparently that's why you suggested to use `?` for null safety during rendering...

Comment: yeah just null check so that it wont crash :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign new object use:

```js
const contentInString = {content: newsEntity.content};
```

If you want to get `content` from `newsEntity` use:

```js
const contentInString = newsEntity.content;
```

Regarding the last part of the question - that's TypeScript error and it gives you the hint that something went wrong with your types.
You can or

- create new variable and type will be inferred automatically
- Or fix the type manually

Comment: btw when I tried to parse using JSON it gives me `Argument of type '{ content: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Comment: That's TypeScript complains about incorrect types. It's saying that assigning object is not allowed into string variable. Simply fix the type of the variable or create new one

Answer (score 0):

```
//Checkout this hopefully this will help you
let GblVar=100;  
 
function Fn() {          //function
 
  console.log(GblVar)
 
  if (true) {         //code block
    console.log(GblVar)
  }
 
  function nested() {         //nested function within someFn1
    console.log(GblVar)
  }
 
}
 
for (let c = 0; c < 3; c++){    //code block
  console.log(GblVar);
}
 
function OthrFn1() {       //another function
  console.log(GblVar)
}
 
console.log(GblVar)
```